# Debugging a remote nodejs project on Netbeans 8.1

Tags: node.js, remote-debugging, netbeans-8

i use netbeans 8.1 and i would like to debug my remote nodejs project. 
So i create a new "php Application from remote server".
Now i can code on my remote project. But is it also possible to run and debug this project directly from the netbeans ide?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use some available plugins on the netbeans site

like http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/36653/nodejs

Download netbeans 8.x.x 
On windows,
1) NetBeans > Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Node.js > Default run command: node D:\WorkSpace\UI\app.js

2) NetBeans > Tools >Options > General > Web Browser > Chrome > Edit > Arguments: http://localhost:8702/#/orders

3) Right-click app.js and "Run with Node.js". This should start your node.

4) Then just simply "Run Project" to access UI locally on Chrome via NetBeans